# Java can't display Unicode characters despite properly configured terminal

Tags: java, unicode, cygwin

I'm trying to print the [Unicode block character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm) in a Java application being run in Cygwin. Despite the terminal being set to UTF-8, and despite Bash and Python being able to print the character, Java simply prints a `?`.

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

$ echo -e "\xe2\x96\x88"
█

$ python3 -c 'print("\u2588")'
█

$ cat Block.java
public class Block {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println('\u2588');
  }
}

$ javac Block.java

$ java -cp . Block
?
```

This appears to be Cygwin-specific, as when run from cmd the character is displayed:

```
>java -cp . Block
█
```

Is there anything I can do to get Cygwin/mintty to render Java's output correctly?

**Update**:

It appears Java on Windows/Cygwin doesn't actually use the `LANG` environment variable, and is therefore actually still using cp1252:

```
$ cat Block.java
public class Block {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Default Charset=" + java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
    System.out.println("\u2588");
  }
}

$ java -cp . Block
Default Charset=windows-1252
?
```

But oddly I can't get [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) to work:

```
$ java -cp . Block | iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF8
Default Charset=windows-1252
?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there's no way to get `java` to respect Cygwin's charset, since Java on Windows doesn't use any environment variables to determine the default encoding.

You can use `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to add flags to the `java` invocation dynamically, however this causes `java` to print debugging information which I'd rather not have.

```
$ JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' java -cp . Block
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Default Charset=UTF-8
█
```

Another option is to use aliases:

```
alias javac='javac -encoding UTF-8'
alias java='java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

Which works well enough for interactive usage.

Comment: `iconv` won't help because `█` cannot be encoded in windows-1252 in the first place (and java will print `?` instead)

Comment: @roeland Why then does it display correctly from a (windows-1252) cmd prompt?

Comment: Because some programs use Windows-specific functions to print text. Regardless of your code page, `WriteConsoleW(...)` for instance can print any Unicode text on the console.