# Clean javac output on Windows for Vim, maybe via Unix (Cygwin) tools

Tags: java, bash, vim, javac

I am new to Java, and installed the following JDK on Windows 10:

```
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-openj9
```

I can invoke the compiler `javac` from Cygwin's Bash command line
(in an x-terminal), but it *creates many errors that seem to go to
neither `stdout` or `stderr`.*  **I need to send them to a file
that I can peruse with Vim.**

Here is my invocation command

```
# mk.bash
# -------
javac \
-classpath "/c/Program Files/.../cplex.jar" \
TestSetup.java
```

The `classpath` argument is irrelevant here, as I
only want to focus on capturing `javac`'s output in a Vim-perusable
way.

Issuing `./mk.bash >| mk.out` generates an empty `mk.out`, as does
`./mk.bash 2>&1 >| mk.out`.  I've used the latter pattern for decades
to redirect stderr to stdout and overwrite the destination file.

I *can* use the `script` command to send the `javac` output to `mk.out`:

```
script mk.out
./mk.bash
exit
```

I can then browse the error messages using `Vim`.  However, the
contents are obfuscated by many binary characters (image & link to file below).  Normally, I can
clean up messy files with `dos2unix`, but on this output, it quits due
to binary characters.

As another way to clean up the non-text content, Vim has a
`fileformat=dos` option which can be entered using `:e ++ff=dos %`.
The `e` and `%` says to edit the current file, while `++ff=dos` says
to interpret the file as `dos` format (`ff` is `fileformat`).  All
this does is clean up visual artifacts due to the different line
endings in Unix and DOS. All the error messages are still interspersed
with what seem like Escape characters `^[`.

**Is there any way to get `javac` to generate only plain text
output or to clean up the output?**

Here is an image of the non-plain-text file in Vim:

[image]

I doubt it is all that relevant, but I'm following this webpage to
compile a simple Java app `TestSetup.java` that invokes a 3rd party
tool: https://kunlei.github.io/cplex/cplex-java-setup.

Comment: Those are ANSI color code escapes. How are you running `javac`? I suspect there's some kind of colorising wrapper script involved.

Comment: I'm invoking the 1-command mk.bash above using the 3 bash commands above starting with `script mk.out`.  As an added sleuthing step, I issued `javac --help` to see if there might be command line options to force plain-text, but nothing was apparent.  I'm hoping that an environment variable might be a possibility, but I don't know.  Also, I'm using **Bash** in an `xterm` to invoke `javac` installed on Windows.

Comment: Vim shows that `javac` is binary, so if it is a wrapper, it isn't a script. I also tried `javac -classpath "c:\Program\ Files\...\cplex.jar" TestSetup.java 2> mk.out` from the DOS command line.  The output in `mk.out` is free of ANSI color code escapes. I need to find a way to do this from Bash. My way ahead is to compare environmental variables in the DOS and Bash command lines.

Comment: I think you will have far more luck using an actual java build tool like maven (or ant) instead of trying to force cygwin and javac to play as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely keep Maven in mind. I'm not a software developer, however, and I know that it can be quite a commitment getting familiar with the development environments and tools for long term benefit. I have to be careful about how I apportion my limited time for a limited-scope task. Meanwhile, I found the only likely environment variable difference between DOS & Bash was `TERM`, but unsetting that didn't change anything. A solution that *did* help was Vim's [`:terminal`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20496/7041) command.

Comment: I'm trying to explain running Windows `javac` in cygwin is not the way to go. The Linux `javac` in the Windows Subsystem for Linux might work for you. But the "correct" and easiest solution, is to use a proper build tool that works across platforms.

Comment: I am curious...what environment *would* the Windows `javac` be good for? I'm guessing it's for some shell, as it is an executable.  Probably not a DOS shell.  Vim is just and editor, and Bash is just a way to get around. I've used them with many different environments and platforms in past decades, sometimes instead of IDEs or command line environments, and sometimes together with them.

Comment: Re. Maven, I haven't ruled that out.  However, we probably occupy different worlds. I am not delivering a product or targeting cross-platform. What I'm investigating has a limited footprint in the development world, and time must be apportioned accordingly (constantly reassessing, of course).

Comment: PowerShell or cmd. cygwin is a posix compatibility library, the windows javac is not compiled to run there. You are not the first person to post questions about odd behavior specifically in cygwin with Java. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042786/2970947

Comment: Thanks, good to know.  As I indicated, really using Bash and Vim at a superficial level, navigating, file management, source editing, output inspection.  I'm not connecting in the bowels of `javac`.  Even so, it is extremely handicapping not to have that.  At that level of superficiality, however, it seems that my most serious problems would be terminal output, and I can avoid that with measures such as the solution to this posted problem.  Most of my I/O will be file oriented, and mostly data sets.  Not user presentation oriented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bottom line up front**

The following Bash command sends both `stdout` and `stderr` from
`javac` to both the screen and the file `mk.out`:

```
javac -classpath /Some/NonExistent/Jar/File.jar TestSetup.java \
2>&1 | tee mk.out
```

**How it was found**

I found that the problem was primarily the use of Bash piping,
redirection, and the `script` command.  The latter is responsible for
the ANSI codes.  I could not determine this previously because I could
not capture the `javac` error messages in a file without `script`.  So
I first solved that problem, then compared the use of `script` with
the absence of `script`.  Here is what I found.

The following bash command creates a DOS format file without the ANSI
codes:

```
javac -classpath '/Some/NonExistent/File.jar' TestSetup.java \
>| mk.out 2>&1
```

Before, I had: **(1)** `2>&1 >| mk.out` instead of **(2)** `>| mk.out 2>&1`.  For option (1), I thought `stderr` became directed to
`stdout`, so I simply needed to direct `stdout` to `mk.out`.

But that's not how it works.  In option (1), the specification `2>&1`
directs `stderr` to what `stdout` is currently directed at, i.e., the
screen.  The subsequent `>| mk.out` then directs `stdout` (and *only*
`std.out`) to `mk.out`.  Unfortunately, this meant that `stderr` was
still going to the screen.  Presto, `mk.out` is left empty (bad).

In option (2), `stdout` is first directed to `mk.out`.  The subsequent
`2>&1` then directs `stderr` to what `stdout` is directed to, i.e.,
`mk.out`.  Hence, the `javac` error messages get sent to `mk.out`.
It did **not** contain ANSI codes, which is good.

While option (2) works, it is not ideal; the error messages are not
shown on the screen.  This is where I fell back to `script` and found
that it introduced the ANSI codes:

```
script \
-c "javac -classpath '/Some/NonExistent/File.jar' TestSetup.java" \
mk.out
```

Since the above solves the problem of redirecting `stderr`, I looked
for bash options that avoid `script`.  The following sends `stderr` to
the screen and to `mk.out`:

```
javac -classpath /Some/NonExistent/Jar/File.jar TestSetup.java \
2>&1 | tee mk.out
```

According to the explanation of option (1) above, it looks like it
shouldn't work, but Bash makes an exception when it is used in a
pipeline.  Specifically, `stderr` is redirected to what `stdout` is
directed to, but only after all redirections.  In a pipeline, the
above means that `javac`'s `stdout` is directed to `tee`'s `stdin`,
and only then is `javac`'s `stderr` directed to the target of
`javac`'s `stdout`, i.e., `tee`'s `stdin`.

**For reference: Initial solution (`javac`'s *Xstdout* option)**

I found that my `javac` has a command line option `-Xstdout OutputFileName.txt` specifically for this purpose.

*Unfortunately,* not all `javac` documentation that I found online shows availability of this option.  In that case, the most direct solution I found was [`:term cat The/Output/File.Path`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20496/7041) in Vim.

Many vim alternatives are also shown on that page, as well as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1445805/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-a-text-file-in-vi)

For future reference, if needed, 3 fulsome pages that I found to be
relevant are:

- https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Mention is made of `ansi2txt`, but you need Ubuntu for that.